# How to fix sizes when I developed my website with 'more space' display setting on macbook retina

Tags: css, macos, retina-display, stylus, retina

I developed a website on a macbook pro with retina, where my display settings are scaled to 'more space'. The webapp looks great this way.

[image: Tuftslife with 'More Space' scale]

But when I set the display back to 'default' scaling, it looks pretty bad, with all the components far too big.

[image: Display Scaling on a mac]
[image: Tuftslife with 'Default' Scale]

How does display scaling work? My best guess is that it's a different mapping between device pixels and CSS pixels, but other websites seem to handle this so much more gracefully. I want my webapp to look roughly the same for people with different resolutions and display settings. Does CSS have any sort of elegant way of handling this? Or does Stylus? (the CSS preprocessor I'm using)

My current plan is to just go through the CSS by hand and cut all the sizes in there in half. But I'd rather not have to go through there if there exists a better way.

Comment: I think it works like it is supposed to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out!

Turns out that when you go back to unscaled "default" view settings, the number of css pixels actually diminishes as well (down to like 1100 or so when fullscreened) and grows to 1500 or so when fullscreened on "more space". So in order not to scale the page, we need a version of the CSS where every px value is A for "more space" and A/2 for "default" (more or less). I was considering doing this by hand, but then realized that I would also have to do this for bootstrap (go through and change every css `px` value from A to A/2. This didn't sound fun.

But then, Bootstrap 4 came out and I learned about the `rem` unit in css. That would mean that if I went through and changed every `px` value to its associated `rem` value, I could do something like:

```
@media(min-width: 768px)
    html
        font-size 12px
@media(min-width: 1150px)
    html
        font-size 14px
@media(min-width: 1300px)
    html
        font-size 16px
```

And that's exactly what I did. In order to do that, I needed to write a script to go through a minified bootstrap string and change px to rem with a base html size of 16:

```
import re

def toRem(match):
    return str(float(match.group(0))/16.0)

def main(string):
    splits = string.split('px')
    values = [re.sub('[0-9]+$', toRem, split) for split in splits]
    output = 'rem'.join(values)
    print output
```

The only issue with this approach was one value: 1px is converted to 0.0625rem, which when you drop the html font size, is too small to display, so all your 1px borders disappear. I fixed this by changin every occurrence of 0.0625rem to 1px, since 1px should always be 1px.

Now the page looks great for all display resolutions, we even preserved the mobile view for sizes below 768px.

Answer (score 0):

what in particular are you having issues with?

Fonts shouldn't really be an issue and you should be using SVG's for your icons.

The only real grey area is images but if you use something like picturefill it should be good enough for the moment.

Furthermore i think you should give [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/set-the-viewport?hl=en) a read.

Comment: Just the sizes of everything. I'll add some photos to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `@media`.

You can check device pixel ratio and set different images or styles.
For example if you want to check is this device has x3 ratio, you should do like this:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 3) {
    .style-of-element {
        background: url();
        font-size 24px;
    }
}
```

If we talk only about images, you can see HTML5 tag `<picture>`. [Link](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-html5-picture-for-responsive-images--cms-21015) 
You can check pixel ratio there also and put different images depending on it. Just like this:

```
   <picture> 
        <source srcset="http://big.jpg" media="(min-width: 617px)">
        <source srcset="http://medium.jpg 1.25x, http://big.jpg 1.5x" media="(min-width: 419px)">
        <source srcset="http://medium.jpg 1.5x, http://big.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 321px)">
        <source srcset="http://medium.jpg 2x, http://big.jpg 3x" media="(min-width: 222px)">
        <img alt="Alt" src="http://default.jpg">
   </picture>
```

Also I know one good presentation about what Retina is, but it is in Russian. May be you will get some understanding from pictures there? [Link](http://pepelsbey.net/pres/clear-and-sharp/)

Comment: Seems like the media query didn't actually work, which surprised me: I did 

`@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)`
 `body`
  `background-color blue !important`

And everything turned blue on both display settings: default **and** 'more space'.

But `@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 3)` turned everything blue in neither display setting case.

Comment: That sounds like pixel ratio doesn't change and it's equal 2. Actually I don't  get a problem. It looks like it supposed to be. Scaled. If you do this for testing on a mobile devices you should install iPhone emulator. It works great on MacOS